# Contar y obtener el porcentaje, con Python, de los votos realizados por n personas a x candidatos

Tags: python, python-3.7

Se supone que debo contar la cantidad de votos realizada por n personas hacia 5 candidatos y a la vez sacar el porcentaje que obtuvo de todos los votantes.

Ejemplo: candidato 1: 10 votos, supongamos que votaron 50 entonces el porcentaje sería *50/10x100*.

He intentado de diversas maneras pero no me sale.

Mi intento es este:

---

```
voto1=0 voto2=0 voto3=0 voto4=0 voto5=0 total_votos=0
  
      voto=int(input("ingrese su voto: "))
      while voto!=0:    if voto==1:
      voto1+=1    elif voto==2:
      voto2+=1    elif voto==3:
      voto3+=1    elif voto==4:
      voto4+=1    elif voto==5:
      voto5+=1    voto=int(input("ingrese su voto: "))
  
  
      total_votos=voto1+voto2+voto3+voto4+voto5
      porcentaje1=voto1/total_votos*100 porcentaje2=voto2/total_votos*100       porcentaje3=voto3/total_votos*100 porcentaje4=voto4/total_votos*100    porcentaje5=voto5/total_votos*100
      print("votos candidato 1: ",voto1,"equivalente al :",porcentaje1,"%")    print("votos candidato 2: ",voto2,"equivalente  al :",porcentaje2,"%")    print("votos candidato 3:    ",voto3,"equivalente al :",porcentaje3,"%")    print("votos candidato  4: ",voto4,"equivalente al :",porcentaje4,"%")    print("votos    candidato 5: ",voto5,"equivalente al :",porcentaje5,"%")
```

Comment: Que error tienes?, te sale algo en la consola, el resultado no es el esperado? Ademas no creo que tu estructura esté muy bien(identacion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tienes que manejar múltiples instancias de una misma cosa, lo correcto es usar listas o tuplas. Usar variables con números no es una solución escalable.

Una versión con listas del ejercicio empieza con

```
max_candidatos = 5
votos = [0] * max_candidatos
```

Para hacer el código más flexible, el número de candidatos en la elección se declara en al variable `max_candidatos`.

Este mismo valor se usa para crear una lista de votos por candidato. La lista tiene tantos elementos como candidatos.

Ahora hay que pedir la votación de cada uno de ellos, e ir agregandola a la lista:

```
for candidato in range(max_candidatos):
    votacion = int(input(f"Ingrese votación candidato {candidato+1}: "))
    votos[candidato] = votacion
```

Para obtener la suma total de votos, simplemente usamos la función `sum` sobre la lista de votos:

```
total_votos = sum(votos)
```

Para calcular los porcentajes, recorremos los candidatos, sacando su votación y calculando el porcentaje:

```
for candidato in range(max_candidatos):
    porcentaje = 100 * votos[candidato] / total_votos
    print(f"Porcentaje candidato {candidato + 1} {porcentaje:.2f}%")
```

**Código completo**

```
max_candidatos = 5
votos = [0] * max_candidatos
for candidato in range(max_candidatos):
    votacion = int(input(f"Ingrese votación candidato {candidato+1}: "))
    votos[candidato] += votacion

total_votos = sum(votos)
for candidato in range(max_candidatos):
    porcentaje = 100 * votos[candidato] / total_votos
    print(f"Porcentaje candidato {candidato + 1} {porcentaje:.2f}%")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese votación candidato 1: 10
Ingrese votación candidato 2: 10
Ingrese votación candidato 3: 20
Ingrese votación candidato 4: 20
Ingrese votación candidato 5: 60
Porcentaje candidato 1 8.33%
Porcentaje candidato 2 8.33%
Porcentaje candidato 3 16.67%
Porcentaje candidato 4 16.67%
Porcentaje candidato 5 50.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

La primera parte de tu código esta bien implementado, de hecho lo he utilizado para realizar tu ejercicio. Luego la última parte de tu código la cambié para implementar una lista de los votos `candidatos = [votos1, votos2, votos3, votos4, votos5]` que la recorre un `for`, con esto lograremos sacar el porcentaje de cada uno sin tener que hacerlo 5 veces.
Con esto podemos hacer un `print()` con el cual diremos lo solicitado (antes de este implementamos un contador que nos diga específicamente en que candidato vamos). Entonces con esto el código sería algo así:

**Código completo:**

```
voto1 = 0
voto2 = 0
voto3 = 0
voto4 = 0
voto5 = 0
voto = int(input('Su voto es para: '))
while voto != 0:
    if voto == 1:
        voto1 += 1
    elif voto == 2:
        voto2 += 1
    elif voto == 3:
        voto3 += 1
    elif voto == 4:
        voto4 += 1
    elif voto == 5:
        voto5 += 1

    voto = int(input('Su voto es para: '))

total_de_votos = voto1 + voto2 + voto3 + voto4 + voto5
candidatos = [voto1, voto2, voto3, voto4, voto5]
print("Total de votos " + str(total_de_votos))
contador = 0
for i in candidatos:
    contador += 1
    porcentaje = str(int((i/total_de_votos)*100)) + "%"
    print("El candidato " + str(contador) + " obtuvo " + str(i) + " votos, lo cual corresponden a un " + porcentaje + " del total de los votos.")
```

Cabe destacar que debes mencionar que para terminar la votación debes ingresar tu voto hacia el candidato "0".

Produce:

```
Total de votos 5
El candidato 1 obtuvo 1 votos, lo cual corresponden a un 20% del total de los votos.
El candidato 2 obtuvo 2 votos, lo cual corresponden a un 40% del total de los votos.
El candidato 3 obtuvo 1 votos, lo cual corresponden a un 20% del total de los votos.
El candidato 4 obtuvo 1 votos, lo cual corresponden a un 20% del total de los votos.
El candidato 5 obtuvo 0 votos, lo cual corresponden a un 0% del total de los votos.
```

En un ejemplo donde el candidato los votos fueron: 1 2 2 3 4 0.